# How to make this contour integral go to zero as $R\to\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to do this using the ML lemma, and realised a small thing that seems to not allow me to show it goes to zero.

By integrating the function $z\rightarrow e^{-z^2}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$ around the contour that is the sum of the line segment $[0,R]$, the quarter circle arc from the point $(R,0)$ to $R(1+i)$ and the line segment from $R(1+i)$ to the origin, show that
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^R \cos t^2 - \sin t^2 \ dt = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^R \cos t^2  + \sin t^2 \ dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$

My trouble is showing the integral goes to zero on the quarter arc. Label this $\Gamma_R$.

$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}e^{-z^2} \ dz\right| \leqslant ML := \max\{|e^{-z^2}|:z\in\mathrm{Range}(\Gamma_R)\}\times \pi R/2  
$$
So on the range of $\Gamma_R$, $z=e^{i\theta}$.
Then 
$$|e^{-z^2}| = e^{-R^2 \cos 2\theta}
$$
So
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}e^{-z^2} \ dz\right| \leqslant ML := e^{-R^2\cos 2\theta}\times \pi R/2
$$
which goes to zero as $R\rightarrow 0$.
But... it seems my $M$ is incorrect. The maximum of the modulus of the function is actually $1$... at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. From there, any $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ is smaller.
So am I incorrect in showing this limit goes to zero?

Comment: ML is not quite strong enough to show the integral tends to $0$. Do you know how Jordan's lemma is proved?

Comment: I cannot remember the proof but I will look back at my notes for it. Iirc, the integrand has to have a factor of $e^{itz}$ for $t>0$ doesn't it?

Comment: Sort of. That's the situation usually considered, but we have more general variants. However, the meat of it is that we consider $$R\cdot \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R\sin \varphi}\,d\varphi$$ and see that that converges to $0$ as $R\to \infty$. Here we have something very similar. Let $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\theta$, then you get a bound of $$\frac{\pi R}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R^2\sin \varphi}\,d\varphi.$$ To estimate that integral, the inequality $\sin \varphi \geqslant \frac{2}{\pi} \varphi$ for $0 \leqslant \varphi \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$ is useful.

Comment: I'll have a go, thank you!  
Also, we haven't really learnt the conditions that justify the interchange of limit and integral (I think this is what you mean by that first integral and what the next step for the second integral is?), but I assume it's valid here?